# Why does Groot freeze still when Drax looks at him

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

At the end of the first *Guardians of the Galaxy*, when Groot is a twig in a pot and at the start of the second film when the Guardians are fighting that Interdimensional monster, we see Groot dancing, but when Drax looks at him, Groot freezes still until Drax is no longer looking at him.

But why is this? I suspect it might be something like how Drax's species doesn't understand metaphors because it's not that Drax doesn't know that Little Groot is alive.

Answer (score 14):

Director gave the answer himself, from [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/2015/02/22/guardians-of-the-galaxy-cut-scene-reveals-why-baby-groot-hid-his/)

> “There was actually a scene that we cut from the movie where big Groot
>   was dancing to 'Livin’ Thing' by ELO,” said Gunn. “And it wasn’t such
>   an elaborate dance. It was more that he was just moving up and down
>   like this, and Drax was dismissive and gave him this look like he was
>   a loser when he did that.”
>
> Gunn added, “Dancing is ludicrous to Drax. I don’t think he
>   understands it. If Drax owned a town, if he was a mayor, the first law
>   would be no dancing. But yeah, so at the end of the movie, little baby
>   Groot didn’t want to get caught dancing, because he would kill him.”

His disgust for dance was more clear in the second film [transcripts](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2):

> **Drax:** Everyone in the village flailed about, dancing. Except one woman. My Ovette. I knew immediately she was the one for me. The most
>   melodic song in the world could be playing. She wouldn’t even tap her
>   foot. Wouldn’t move a muscle. One might assume she was dead.
>
> **Quill:** That does sound pretty hot.
>
> **Drax:** It would make my nether regions engorge.
>
> **Quill:** Okay. I get it, yes. I’m a dancer, Gamora is not.
>
> **Drax:** You just need to find a woman who is pathetic… like you.

Comment: Fixed a typo! :P

Comment: I sense a future mash-up of Footloose and Guardians of the Galaxy being pitched in Hollywood.

Comment: IIRC from the commentary, the specific reason is because he wants Drax to like and respect him. Which would also explain why Drax is the only one Groot physically lashes out at. Drax is a warrior, so Groot responds like a warrior when Drax annoys him.

Answer (score 4):

Groot always freezes because he knows Drax disapproves of it. This also happens at the start of Guardians of the Galaxy 2.

Drax even explains later that he was attracted to his wife because she stood still and did not dance.